# java android : resize appbarlayout when hide a specific relativelayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml, android-appbarlayout

I have a bug in android development.

I would like resize the appbarlayout when I hide a relative layout Contained in it. but the height of appbarlayout is not reloaded and so I have a bar blue.

Here is the result obtained :

[image]

I hide this relative layout when my adapter is empty.
Do you have any idea how to remedy this?

xml :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

/// I want hide this Relative Layout
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_recycler_view"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_set_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:onClick="onClickToScrollToBegin"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_double_arrow_up" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/rv_recycler_view"
        app:layout_behavior="com.brick_reader.brick_reader.FABScrollBehavior"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.